# An onload javascript to get page entered from; then set two css id to display:none' and "display:inline' toggling two <a href link options available

Tags: javascript, css, html

Please, I am light on javascript wizardry. I would be grateful with help on a  run upon page loading, returning a value or string for what ultimate local path it came from in order to instruct the rest of the script to either/or the result (to a hard coded comparison); and, given the results, toggle two css id which would respectively have one id containing a "display:none" and the other a "display:inline" to control the way the bottom of page is href linked with navigation choices of design determined by which of two different menu pages is its actual originating parent.
The css id(s) spoken of would be initially set locally in the new content child page 'style' section as say:

```
#MyDisplayOnOff-0 {display:inline;}
and
#MyDisplayOnOff-1 {display:none;}
```

The href sending page will be one of two menus eg simplified:
"./MenuONE.html" or "./MenuONE.html#Top" or "./MenuONE.html#Bottom"
OR
"./SECONDMenu.html" or "./SECONDMenu.html#Top" or "./SECONDMenu.html#Bottom"

[actual example for ./MenuONE.html]:

http://gladheart.royalwebhosting.net/Menu%20-%20Of%20Lila%20and%20the%20Void.html

http://gladheart.royalwebhosting.net/Menu%20-%20Of%20Lila%20and%20the%20Void.html#Bottom

http://gladheart.royalwebhosting.net/Menu%20-%20Of%20Lila%20and%20the%20Void.html#Top

So far, when identical content has been selected from one of two different menus, I have been creating two html pages (of slightly varied name), containing the same content but with different navigation links at the bottom. I would rather use one html page, hard coded with the two alternate links, and then with the result of the initial javascript return of 'sending page', appropriately populate the two css id(s) with one as 'display:none' and the other as 'display:inline' in order to display just one of the two

Here are two real world examples of the same content on separate [slightly differently named] html pages each with a different bottom  link structure, necessitated in design by each being evoked from a distinct menu.

http://gladheart.royalwebhosting.net/Poetry%20-%20Time%20and%20i.html
http://gladheart.royalwebhosting.net/Poetry%20-%20Time%20and%20i-L.html

What I feel might be needed in javascript is:

<[pseudo-]script>

```
query to determine [get.previous] 'sending-page'


take the string query as returned above [which would be
either eg. 
http://gladheart.royalwebhosting.net/MenuONE.html]
or
http://gladheart.royalwebhosting.net/MenuONE.html]
and parse from right to left over to the  first '/' 
[forward slash] and then discard that forward slash
and all else to the left of it; OR, as an option, just
check the whole string for any one of the six targeted
strings contained in the 'if' conditional statements below.
[[Actually here, a simplified two word word search for either
"MenuONE" or "SECONDMenu" being contained in the string being
evaluated would return the needed result to proceed.]]


if 'sending-page' equal
    "MenuONE.html"
    or
    "MenuONE.html#Top"
    or
    "MenuONE.html#Bottom"
do nothing


if 'sending-page' equal
    "SecondMenu.html"
    or
    "SecondMenu.html#Top"
    or
    "SecondMenu.html#Bottom"
do change
    #MyDisplayOnOff-0 {display:inline;} instead to #MyDisplayOnOff-0 {display:none;}
    and
    #MyDisplayOnOff-1 {display:none;} instead to #MyDisplayOnOff-1 {display:inline;
```

I have been asked to add the html used. The body of the html content (poems) has links at the bottom, for example;

```
<div id="BottomRightpNAV">
    <a href="./Menu%20-%20Rivers%20of%20Mind%20and%20Heart.html">Rivers of Mind and Heart</a>
</div>
```

My intention is to add a second link; and with added id(s) on both for toggling which one to display. They (the id(s)) would be initially set with css in the local 'style' section as:

```
#MyDisplayOnOff-0 {display:inline;}
and
#MyDisplayOnOff-1 {display:none;}
```

The link example (one comment up above the css 'style shown in discussion immediately above) would then, in an arbitrary example, have a second different link optioned in. Only one at a time would show. Each link, with the inclusions of a css id [effectively allowing one or the other to be turned on or off], would be shown together hard coded as immediately below.

```
<div id="BottomRightpNAV">
    <a id="MyDisplayOnOff-0" href="./Menu%20-%20Rivers%20of%20Mind%20and%20Heart.html">Rivers of Mind and Heart</a>

    <a id="MyDisplayOnOff-1" href="./Menu%20-%20Of%20Lila%20and%20the%20Void.html">Of Lila and the Void</a>
</div>
```

Thus, in total depending on which page (in this case one of two menus) the user entered from, it would display as deemed appropriate  one of two links available and hide ['display:none;'] the other link.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what's being asked. I also generally won't visit source websites since 1. links die, 2. what if it's malicious? and 3. it often makes the problem more confusing. Would you be willing to build a code snippet with at least the HTML?

Comment: Thank you @stealththeninja. I am sorry if I am unclear. I did add a <[psuedo-]script> needed in javascript after first posting for clarity. The html I use is content (a poem) and then at the bottom of the page, local path href's such as                                              <div id="BottomRightpNAV">
      <a href="./Menu%20-%20Rivers%20of%20Mind%20and%20Heart.html
   ">Rivers of Mind and Heart</a>
 </div>

Comment: So... You want to either show or hide an element depending on what the URL of the page is?

Comment: CodeF0x, thank you. Yes, if it is assumed in understanding that the URL refered to is the URL of the page upon whose link was clicked and then generated the journey to the new content page  The new content page is where we wish to do an onload query regarding that URL and hide or show the desired element [link] depending on whether it was URL-a or URL-b.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was initiated thanks to the excellent advice and code example offered by @Andu Andrici. It was achieved by 'pushing' the information from a parent Menu pageA or a pageB in order to identify which page opened up the common child content page. Trying to get the originating page from history with its security restraints, or (outside of cookies) the (again security) inability to write to css or script files made this an ideal and elegant solution. On the child content page, common to both Menu pages, it was javascript'd with 'if' statements: and the unchanged content thus had unique and differentiating links then arbitrarily placed at the bottom.

zMenuA.html is simplified below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>zMenuA.html [Acknowledgement @Andu Andrici]</title>
</head>
<body>

<a href="./zSameTarget.html?redictedFrom=zMenuA">zMenuA.html invoking zSameTarget.html</a>

</body>
</html>
```

zMenuB.html linking to the same content is near identical and is simplified below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>zMenuB.html [Acknowledgement @Andu Andrici]</title>
</head>
<body>

<a href="./zSameTarget.html?redictedFrom=zMenuB">zMenuB.html invoking zSameTarget.html</a>

</body>
</html>
```

'zSameTarget.html', the content page with its 'on/off - either/or' navigation link being set by evaluating which page was its parent, is simplified below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>zSameTarget.html [Acknowledgement @Andu Andrici]</title>
<style></style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var MyAppendedUrlMarker = window.location.search

    if (MyAppendedUrlMarker === '?redictedFrom=zMenuA') {
    onload = function () {
    document.head.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', "<link href='addOtherCSSstyling.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet'/>");

        var MyElement = 
document.getElementById("MyDisplayOnOff0").style.display = "inline";
        var MyElement = 
document.getElementById("MyDisplayOnOff1").style.display = "none";
        }
    }

    if (MyAppendedUrlMarker === '?redictedFrom=zMenuB') { 
    onload = function () {
        var MyElement = 
document.getElementById("MyDisplayOnOff0").style.display = "none";
        var MyElement = 
document.getElementById("MyDisplayOnOff1").style.display = "inline";
        }        
    }
</script>

</head>

<body>

<p style="white-space:pre-wrap;">
This is the child page 'zSameTarget.html' with this content showing 
the same; BUT, at the bottom, with different content [a navigation link] 
being visible and active, solely dictated by which parent page invoked 
this page. To whit, whether in opening this page, an [a href ....] was 
clicked on 'zMenuA.html', or if it came from a click originating from 
'zMenuB.html' instead. NOTE: running this page alone will show two links. 
It is meant to show only one link. Therefore, first open 'zMenuA.html' 
or 'zMenuB.html' and then link to this page from either one of them. As
indicated, depending on the page chosen, one will find it has produced a 
different content [link in this case] visible at the bottom. As well, I 
have added a linked 'myFile.css' to modify the styling elsewhere when
'zMenuA.html' is identified as the parent in the 'if' statements.</p><br/>

    <div>
<a id="MyDisplayOnOff0" href="./Menu%20-%20Rivers%20of%20Mind%20and%20Heart.html">Rivers of Mind and Heart</a> 
<br/>
<a id="MyDisplayOnOff1" href="./Menu%20-%20Of%20Lila%20and%20the%20Void.html">Of Lila and the Void</a> 
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you could try something like this:

Make each link include a query parameter:

```
<a href="something.com?redictedFrom=page1">my link's text</a>
<a href="something.com?redictedFrom=page2">my link's text</a>
```

The query parameter is what comes after the '**?**' within the link, and it acts like a HTML custom attribute :

it's recommended fot it to be a key-value pair

it can have any name - **redictedFrom** is the example, but it can be anything

and any value - although it will initially be parsed as a string, as the url itself is a string.

Then, on the page it is redirecting to, you can do something like:

```
// get the page's url and check it
var query = window.location.search // will give you the query string, in this example it will be **redictedFrom=page1**
// then you can then search the string to see if contains what you needed
if (query.indexOf("redictedFrom=page1") > -1) { /* do magic */ }
```

You can also use window.location.search.split('&') to get individual key-value pairs, and also separate them with string.split('='). But that is beyond the immediate scope of the question.

Comment: Thank you @Andu Andrici I will try to get up to speed and incorporate your thoughts and knowledge upon the new day. I am most grateful for your input.

Comment: Glad it helped. Let me know if it works out. Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you @Andu Andrici I have worked your excellent code to the point of returning your query string of ?redictedFrom=zpage1 to an alert box on page2. Before proceeding further, please, what in my case would be most functionally simple for a numer of reasons [including six menu pages treated simplified as page1], instead of re-coding the individually necessary hrefs on page1, would be to have page1 (in this case) upon loading, just do the deed by appending ?redictedFrom=zpage1 to any content <href'd from that page .Is this possible?

Comment: Kudos @Andu Andrici. Starting with your code provided, I have posted in my working and situationally relevant final answer. Tweaking forward, is it possible to have the initiating pages appended the now individually href coded 'query parameter', instead by directing any href clicked on the page have the 'query parameter' (globally for the page) appended. Even better in my case would be to be to dictate the 'query parameter' appending be applicable within a certain [nav tag section or a specific (for-instance) [article tag designated section. Are any of these three options possible?